# Как взять имя приглашенного человека через users.get?

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Как я понимаю нужно брать имя вступившего в беседу ВК вот так:

```
vk_api.users.get(user_id=1)
```

или

```
vk_api.users.get.fields['first_name']
```

но ничего не выводит, в чем моя ошибка?

Answer (score 0):

Если еще актуально

```
vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(login=login, password=password)
vk_session.auth()
vk = vk_session.get_api()     
response = vk.users.get(user_ids=id)
print(response[0]["first_name"])
```